# Error running AudioIntervals on ExampleData

Tags: sound

I get a strange error when running:

```
a = ExampleData[{"Audio", "MaleVoice"}, "Audio"]
voiced = AudioIntervals[a, #VoiceActivity == 1 &, .1, 
  PartitionGranularity -> {.06, .01}]
```

> Function::slot: Slot[#VoiceActivity==1&] (in
> Slot[#VoiceActivity==1&]==1&) should contain a non-negative integer or
> string.
>
> Function::slot: Slot[#1==1&] (in Slot[#1==1&]==1&) should contain a
> non-negative integer or string.
>
> AudioIntervals::prop: #VoiceActivity==1& is not a valid test.

Could this be a Mathematica bug or some internal error? Normally the examples work well.

Any ideas, what the problem could be?

my Mathematica version is 12.1.1.0

Comment: This must be a bug of some kind. There's the exact same documentation example here https://wolfram.com/xid/0g7ibczwwec-6lkjwo and it doesn't work for me when pasting into a fresh 12.1.1.0 kernel.